# jQuery draggable + sortable: strange mouse offset behaviour

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

I have draggable list of < li > elements which I'm able to drag into another empty < ul > element. If I drag the first < li > element of the draggable original < ul > everything works fine...

**Problem:**

...but when I drag any other < li > element of that list the 'helper' moves away from the mouse pointer as soon as I cross the border of the recieving sortable < ul >. More precicely it moves up to the top of the list.

Has anyone seen this and knows a solution?
Well, my problem is, I'm just using jquery, not really deeply into it and never really used javascript in depth either.

More info about the problem:

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#roleList > li').draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#roleDrop',
        containment: '#container',
        revert: 'invalid'
    });                   
    $('#roleDrop').sortable({
        cursor: 'move',
        containment: '#container',
        revert: true,
        update: function() {
            var order = $('#roleDrop').sortable('serialize');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '".$postUrl."',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: order
            });
        }                          
    });
    $('#roleList').disableSelection();
});
```

While #roleList and #roleDrop are the aforementioned unordered lists, #container is a table.

Now a screenshot of what happens.

I start dragging the item:

http://drop.io/download/public/dkabw5hlq3yfm0f84yji/7bf91122adc241373a5da13b5bde4b231644c1c5/da142000-ff76-012b-41ee-f10bc9db08a6/5a1bfa70-68f6-012c-6d08-f2025930ce6a/v2/thumbnail_large

When I cross the border of the second < ul > the helper jumps up.

http://drop.io/download/public/dkabw5hlq3yfm0f84yji/2fad1d633d38cf593da46c638d1930431ea5fd35/da142000-ff76-012b-41ee-f10bc9db08a6/5c65c4c0-68f6-012c-6601-f12da00d9d47/v2/thumbnail_large

If you need the xhtml markup too, please tell me.

Comment: Please post your Javascript/JQuery and relevant HTML code. If you can isolate the problem in a separate HTML file and cut and paste the whole thing, that would be ideal.

Comment: ok, I'll do that tomorrow, it's too late to think now...

Comment: jQuery and screenshots added!

Comment: The XHTML markup would be helpful.

Comment: The containment could cause the issue. Need to see the markup, especially for that #container element. A link to a testpage would be even better.

Comment: Any CSS would be pretty helpful as well

Comment: I'll try to deliver. I'm a bit in trouble with time and internet access. On the road.

Comment: I messed around with your code for a while today and it seems that when the actual text of your list item hits the border, the "top" attribute doesn't get set to correct position of the second container until it crosses the border. Ron's solution below seems to be the only way to prevent this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding `helper: 'clone'` to your `.draggable` options:

```
$('#roleList > li').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    connectToSortable: '#roleDrop',
    containment: '#container',
    revert: 'invalid'
});
```

According to [the jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-connectToSortable), you should set this option when connecting a draggable to a sortable.

While this yields a different interface experience (dragged items are cloned instead of moved), it's at least a temporary workaround for what the documentation implies is a known problem. Additional event handling could clean the original item out of `#roleList` during the `#roleDrop` update callback.